# Variable is nil except when being printed (ERB Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use a variable in a view, and I've isolated an issue I am having a hard time explaining.

If I do this (to check the value is indeed set):

```
<%=
story.id
%>
```

The variable value prints correctly in each row (they are ID numbers).

The variable clearly has a value.

If I so much as try to use the variable however

```
<%=
Integer(story.id)
%>
```

I get a failure

```
ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert nil into Integer):

    43: Integer(story.id)
```

If I remove the call to `Integer()` and simply leave the variable there, it starts printing he value again.

*When a variable demonstrably has a value, why is it being recognized as `nil` when dereferenced?*

Or, asked another way,

*Why is the variable nil **If And Only If** it is used as an argument to a method/function ?*

Comment: Why do you use concat and not `<%= story.id %>` ? Are you writing you're own helper and you're inside a block?

Comment: clarified. I am trying to debug it. doesn't matter if it's concat. Why is calling `Integer()` (or any function for that matter) on a variable that has a value making that value look like it is nil?

Comment: fixed. not using concat anymore. still mystifying.

Comment: Are you doing this inside a loop to output multiple story objects? Are you sure you don't just happen to have one story object on your list with a nil id? Try outputting story.inspect instead of id to see if every object has an id.

Comment: @struthersneil You are absolutely correct. I am not used to implicitly looped code (I did not see a loop, I did not think of it...); I am used to seeing output before errors happen, not an all-or-nothing result... I learn today. My humble thanks! (If you have any notes or advice to add, an Answer would indeed be appropriate)